# WF 4.5 : Creating Custom composite activity

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am looking to create a custom composite activity in WF 4.5

The problem statement :

Create a custom activity with some pre defined properties and variables.
The developer should be able to use this activity as a base and drag and drop other out of the box/ custom activities in it.

I have looked at various samples on the net and I have found the following sample which does exactly what i need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa480200

However it seems that with WF 4.5 the classes mentioned in the sample above have been deprecated. 
Is there a way to achieve what is done the sample above in WF 4.5 ?

Any links articles  or samples which show how this can be done in WF 4.5 would help.

Comment: You should follow the sample for .NET 4.5 instead, more specifically the [composite activities samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759022.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WF4 composite activities can be achieved through [IActivityTemplateFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.iactivitytemplatefactory.aspx):

```
public sealed class CompositeActivity : IActivityTemplateFactory
{
    public Activity Create(DependencyObject target)
    {
        return new Sequence
        {
            Variables = {
                new Variable<string>("MyStringVar"),
                new Variable<int>("MyIntegerVar")
            },
            Activities = {
                new WriteLine { Text = "My first activity within the composite" },
                new Delay { Duration = new InArgument<TimeSpan>(a => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)) },
                new WriteLine { Text = "My third activity within the composite" }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The designer knows *IActivityTemplateFactory* so it will show up on toolbox as any other activity.

Comment: thanks @Jota I used your answer and some more research to achieve my objective. I ended up deriving my custom class from  NativeActivity and IActivityTemplateFactory.